# NHibernate.QueryException : duplicate association path

Tags: c#, nhibernate, criteria

The code fragment below describes what I want to do using queries but it blows up with the above error.

There is a 1 to many relationship between Buildings and AttributeValues and my aim is to find all Buildings which have an `AttributeValue` of `"Large"` and an `AttributeValue` of `"Blue"`.

```
        var attributeValueAlias1 = new AttributeValue();
        var attributeValueAlias2 = new AttributeValue();

        var result = repository
            .CreateCriteriaFor<Buildings>()
            .Join(o=>o.AttributeValues, ()=> attributeValueAlias1)
            .Join(o=>o.AttributeValues, ()=> attributeValueAlias2)
            .Add(() => attributeValueAlias1.Value == "Large")
            .Add(() => attributeValueAlias2.Value == "Blue")
            .List();
```

There are few posts out there but none with a solution to the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940922/duplicate-association-path-error-in-hibernate) and [here](http://blog.dezfowler.com/2008/06/duplicate-association-path-bug-in.html).

I can make it so a membership test is added using `criteria.GetCriteriaByAlias(alias)` before adding the alias so the Duplicate alias error does not occur but then there is only a single join and it results in a SQL where clause which will never be true

```
SELECT *
FROM Buildings  this_
    inner join AttributeValues attributev1_
    on this_.Id = attributev1_.BuildingId
WHERE 
    attributev1_.Value = 'Large'
    and attributev1_.Value = 'Blue'
```

It is not a complicated or unusual query so I'd be surprised if there isn't a work around.

Comment: Similar question here: [Duplicate Association](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881286/i-am-getting-a-duplicate-association-path-error-in-the-nhibernate-criteria-whe) Hope it helps - can't test it at work.

Comment: Just for info I have managed to create an equivalent working query 
using HQL but would prefer not to have to move our dynamic criteria 
based querying over to HQL if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - they seem to come to the same conclusion that it can't be done with Criteria but it seems surprising given it is such a simple query.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a join to do this, as you probably guessed from the exception. You should use two subqueries to test if the values "Blue"  and "Large" are in the collection. I'm not great at ICriteria, but the resulting SQL should look like this and I think this is possible in ICriteria (using `Subqueries.PropertyIn`).

```
select * from Buildings b
inner join AttributeValues av on b.Id = av.BuildingId
where av.Id in (select Id from AttributeValues av2 where av2.BuildingId=b.BuildingId and  av2.Value="Large")
and av.Id in (select Id from AttributeValues av3 where av3.BuildingId=b.BuildingId and av3.Value="Blue")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Pieter.We did look at subqueries but were unable to figure out how to mimic the on clause of a join in the subquery by passing an id from the outer query to the inner query using criteria. In the end we have gone with HQL which gives us the flexibility to have multiple joins.

Comment: Neil, you can do that by associating an alias with the outer query. You can use that alias in the inner query and use `Expression.EqProperty` to compare the Id-values.